# YQL yahoo.finance.xchange historical data

Tags: javascript, yql

This query is working from me

```
select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("EURUSD","GBPUSD")
```

can be seen in the following link:

[https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select+*+from+yahoo.finance.xchange+where+pair+in+(%22EURUSD%22%2C%22GBPUSD%22)](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys#h=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20(%22EURUSD%22%2C%22GBPUSD%22))

But i am looking to get the rates for a specific date, such as the following query:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.xchange where pair in ("EURUSD","GBPUSD") and date = "2009-09-11"
```

What is wrong with my query

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation [over here](http://www.datatables.org/yahoo/finance/yahoo.finance.xchange.xml) there is no other query parameter besides `pair`.

However, there is a currency converter [here](http://finance.yahoo.com/currency-converter/#from=USD;to=EUR;amt=1) which allows to select a date. When analysing the request made whenever you change the selected date, you will notice an ajax request is made to `http://finance.yahoo.com/connection/currency-converter-cache?date=20090911`. Using that, you should be able to extract and convert the needed data.

That JSON request contains several currencies, each of them relative to the US-Dollar. So having this JSON result:

```
{
    "resource":{
        "classname":"Quote",
        "fields":{
            "date":"2015-07-01",
            "price":"0.89807",
            "symbol":"EUR=X",
            "type":"currency"
        }
    }
}
```

means having an exchange rate of `1 USD = 0.8981 EUR`.

**Found the original solution [here](http://dimmys.blogspot.de/2014/01/how-to-get-todays-exchange-rate-and.html)**. Before using the above mentioned source, please check for license issues - I do not know if one is allowed to use the source that way.